# ¿Cómo obtengo las horas y minutos?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy realizando la suma de horas y minutos. Me realiza la suma, pero no de horas, solo la suma normal.

Ejemplo- Ésta es la suma que realiza y no es lo que busco:

```
09:15:00 + 12:15:00 = 21:30:00
```

debería mostrarme esta suma:

```
09:15:00 + 12:15:00 = 03:30:00
```

Éste es mi código:

```js
function calcular(f) {
  horas1 = f['hora1'].value.split(":");
  horas2 = f['hora2'].value.split(":");
  horatotale = new Array();
  for (a = 0; a < 3; a++) {
    horas1[a] = (isNaN(parseInt(horas1[a]))) ? 0 : parseInt(horas1[a])
    horas2[a] = (isNaN(parseInt(horas2[a]))) ? 0 : parseInt(horas2[a])
    horatotale[a] = (horas1[a] + horas2[a]);
  }
  horatotal = new Date()
  horatotal.setHours(horatotale[0]);
  horatotal.setMinutes(horatotale[1]);
  horatotal.setSeconds(horatotale[2]);

  f['horatotal'].value = horatotal.getHours() + ":" + horatotal.getMinutes() + ":" + horatotal.getSeconds();

}
```

```html
<h1>Sumatoria De Horas</h1>

<form action="#" onsubmit="calcular(this);return false">
  <input type="text" name="hora1" onblur="calcular(this.form)" /> +
  <input type="text" name="hora2" onblur="calcular(this.form)" /> =
  <input type="text" name="horatotal" /> <input type="submit" value="calcular" />
</form>
```

Comment: No entiendo porque 9:15 + 12:15 = 3:30?

Comment: cuantas horas hay entre las 9:00 de la mañana y las 12:00 del medio dia?

Comment: Entonces no seria resta de horas?

Comment: Eso no es una suma, es la diferencia de horas que no es lo mismo. Debes editar tu pregunta para aclarar cuál es el problema específico y que sea más fácil ayudarte. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información y recomendaciones.

Comment: Y ademas el resultado no seria 3:30 sino 3:00

Comment: igual como dices no funciona

Comment: La pregunta de @CristianAntonioTrujilloGris parece una broma porque no dice 12M dice 12:00 del medio día que podría entenderse como 12 horas contadas a partir del medio día; trata de generar una paradoja de lenguaje para poner la gente a especular. ¡No me gusta esa actitud!

Comment: pregunto cuanto tiempo hay entre 9:15 y 12:15?                                    no hay 3:30?

Comment: @CristianAntonioTrujilloGris edita la pregunta para aclarar ese punto. En la pregunta se pide una cosa, pero en los comentarios estás pidiendo otra cosa diferente.

Comment: Primero aprende a restar y despues a programar.

Comment: Para responder a la pregunta principal hacen falta unas precisiones: 1. Se suponen las dos horas en el mismo día (si-no) 2. ¿Cómo se va a afectar el elemento date si la suma de horas es mayor que 24 (implica pasar a día siguiente) o si va a ser modular y regresa a primeras horas? Por favor edita la pregunta precisando el contexto

Comment: en ningun momento especifique fechas solamente estoy trabajando con 24 horas

Answer (score 0):

Para saber la diferencia entre una hora y otra lo que propongo es convertir cada "hora" a una medida base (segundos).

Hacer la resta en segundos.

Y al resultado de la resta convertirlo al formato hh:mm:ss

```js
function horasASegundos(hr){
  return parseInt(hr) * 3600;
}

function minutosASegundos(min){
  return parseInt(min) * 60;
}

//Basada en https://stackoverflow.com/a/1322798/7157829
function formatearSegundos(totalSegundos){
  var h = parseInt(totalSegundos / 3600);
  totalSegundos %= 3600;
  var m = Math.floor(totalSegundos / 60);
  var s = totalSegundos % 60;
  return h.toString().padStart(2, "0") + ':' + m.toString().padStart(2, "0") + ':' + s.toString().padStart(2, "0");
}

function calcular(f) {
  //Obtener en arrays la hora separada en Horas, Minutos, Segundos
  var arrHora1 = f['hora1'].value.split(":");
  var arrHora2 = f['hora2'].value.split(":");
  
  //Convertir cada hora a segundos
  var segundosHora1 = horasASegundos(arrHora1[0]) + minutosASegundos(arrHora1[1]) + parseInt(arrHora1[2]);
  var segundosHora2 = horasASegundos(arrHora2[0]) + minutosASegundos(arrHora2[1]) + parseInt(arrHora2[2]);
  
  //Obtener la diferencia en segundos
  var diferencia = segundosHora2 - segundosHora1;
  
  //Agregar el signo de menos si es necesario
  var signo = diferencia < 0 ? '-' : '';
  
  //Formatear los segundos a hh:mm:ss
  f['horatotal'].value = signo + formatearSegundos(Math.abs(diferencia));
}
```

```html
<h1>Sumatoria De Horas</h1>

<form action="#" onsubmit="calcular(this);return false">
  <input type="text" name="hora1" onblur="calcular(this.form)" /> +
  <input type="text" name="hora2" onblur="calcular(this.form)" /> =
  <input type="text" name="horatotal" /> <input type="submit" value="calcular" />
</form>
```